# Labels don't retain their text when Post back happenes because of a selected Index Change of a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET.
In there I have a page where user can write articles. So what ever the user types within textboxes will appear in a preview window which was positioned fixed to the right side of the screen. The problem is that there are a few dropdowns available which Autopostback value set to true, so after the user types something in the textbox and if user selected an item from the dropdown list Page post back occurs and everything in preview window cleared. All the things are placed inside update panels.

Here is my preview window code sample

```
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPreviewContactName"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPreviewContactEmail"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
       <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPreviewContactPhone"></asp:Label>
```

I use javascript to change the text of the Label controls real time when ever user type something on textbox. So after post back happens label's text were cleared.

I know there is something to do with Viewstate. So where to apply that. ? 
Is there any event fired when ever post back happens? So then I can place my all my viewstate saving mechanisms there.

Comment: If you change the value of a label client-side that's not going to be sent back to the server so once the page posts back they get cleared. You have to change something else as well that posts back so you can then reset the labels during postback. In addition to modifying the label, create an asp.net hidden form field that corresponds to each label and change it's value as well. Then in postback, check for that value and set the corresponding label's text property to whatever the hidden field contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use **textbox** (multiline) instead of a **label**. ASP.net labels are only designed to be changed at the server side, so any client side(javascript,in the browser) changes performed on a label will **not** be maintained in the **view state** thus will get reset after postback. But the changes made to a **textbox** will prevail even after postback as they are **maintained in the viewstate**

You can also give some CSS styling to textbox so that it will look like a label.